# Ошибка сервера Minecraft

Tags: java

Друзей выкидывает с сервера Minecraft выдает:

> Internal exception: Java.net.SocketTimeoutExcpetion:Red Timed out. А я остаюсь. Что делать?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию.

Answer (score 4):

- Проверьте настойки сервера, отключен ли онлайн мод `online-mode=false`
- Включен ли `white-list=true`
- Используете ли вы и ваши друзья идентичные версии сервера и клиентов
- Для установки имён используйте `MinecraftSP.exe`
- Если пытаетесь сделать локальный сервер через интеренет используйте Hamachi. Вашим друзья нужно будет вводить id Hamachi, который получмте после создания группы-локальных пользователей.

Это исключительно для локального сервера, к которому можно подключаться через интернет.

Да, запустив файл сервера он создаст файлы настороек и файл white-list. Сделайте в них изменения и перезапустите сервер.

В `white-list` введите ники ваших друзей и вас. Через `Enter`: